# Academy Awards Live Chat - 2015

Tags: discussion, chat, scheduled-event

On February the 22nd/23rd (depending where you are) the [**87th Academy Awards (Oscar) ceremony**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/87th_Academy_Awards) will be held and broadcast live into the world. While not everyone might agree about their true artistic and critical significance, it isn't deniable that they're one of the biggest events in and about one of the biggest and most famous movie industries in the world and, to me at least, a fun event I usually enjoy (albeit having to sacrifice my night sleep for it). It might thus be a great chance for a **simultaneous live chat event during the ceremony**, which could help to make users aware of the chat, and maybe even a few SE users aware of our site.

So we are holding a corresponding **[chat event on 2015-02-23 1:00 - 6:00 UTC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=schedule)** for discussing anything Oscar, be it how hot *Neil Patrick Harris* looks in his suit, how surprising *Jake Gyllenhaal*'s outburst was, or why they let *John Travolta* on the stage again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the Oscars are over and so is the live chat event. Over the [course of the event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1888/2015/2/23) we had a whole of 12 different users chatting and I want to thank everyone for participating and hope you enjoyed it (along with the actual award show, of course).

In addition to that, *Catija* made a little survey for everyone to vote on their own favourites for various specific awards, the results of which [can be viewed here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1791EH07lwOEH23ET6c5Im_4T3GNxuiSM9r2eOM-rkdw/viewanalytics?usp=form_confirm).

I'm looking forward to next year's Academy Awards Chat.

Comment: It will look good if you add results in the answer.