# Oscar Topic Challenge Part I: The nominees for Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Next sunday sees the celebration of the [87th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/87th_Academy_Awards). This might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1482/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2015-02-16 00:00 UTC to 2015-02-23 01:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [american-sniper](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-sniper), [birdman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birdman), [boyhood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boyhood), [the-grand-budapest-hotel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-grand-budapest-hotel), [the-imitation-game](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-imitation-game), [selma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selma), [the-theory-of-everything](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-theory-of-everything) and [whiplash](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiplash)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge. And you might also want to check out our [live chat event](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1614/49) during the actual ceremony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted questions** (with a score of 2 and 32/74 views respectively) were asked by [*Skal*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/18984) and [*Napoleon Wilson*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49), which makes them the winners of this challenge:

## 1. [Which book about encryption did Christopher give Alan when he was a child?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31164/49)

## [Why did Riggan Thomson choose to end his play that way?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31361/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [In what way did Dmitri intend to insult M Gustave at the funeral?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31246/49) (1 / ~43)

   [How does M. Gustave's poem relate to the "Boy with Apple"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31286/49) (1 / ~49)