# Oscar 2016 Topic Challenge I: The nominees for Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Next sunday sees the celebration of the [88th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/88th_Academy_Awards). Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1629/49) this might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2081/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2016-02-22 00:00 UTC to 2016-02-28 23:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [the-big-short](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-big-short), [bridge-of-spies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridge-of-spies), [brooklyn](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brooklyn), [mad-max-fury-road](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mad-max-fury-road), [the-martian](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-martian), [the-revenant](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-revenant), [room](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/room) and [spotlight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spotlight)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge. And you might also want to check out our [live chat event](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2164/49) during the actual ceremony.

Comment: Only watched one of them and have no question on it either.

Comment: Mad Max for Best Picture?  Seriously??  I enjoyed The Peanuts Movie more than that one.  Actually, I enjoyed The Peanuts Movie more than almost anything else I saw this year.  I *will* say this, though; if DiCaprio doesn't win an award for The Revenant, he got ripped off.  He was a powerhouse in that movie.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Why not? Better than all 8 places filled with pseudo-deep biopic crap that would have worked better as a BBC TV movie. As to to DiCaprio, it's unfortunate that this is his highest chance ever to win it, while being more due to a false sense of authenticity rather than the genuine acting chops that brought him all his previous nominations.

Comment: The room is nominated for Oscar? Tommy Wiseau will be so pleased. "You're tearing me apart, Lisa!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 10 and 45 views respectively) was asked by [*user30794*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/30794), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Did The Revenant movie team kill animals for the movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49445/49)

The other question asked, had a score of 1 and 22 views:

2. [What did the German street thugs say to Donovan when they stole his coat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49120/49)