# Oscar 2017 Topic Challenge I: The nominees for Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Next sunday sees the celebration of the [89th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards). Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/oscar-2016-topic-challenge-i-the-nominees-for-best-picture-completed) this might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2607/1190) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2017-02-20 00:00 UTC to 2017-02-26 23:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [arrival](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrival), [fences](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fences), [hacksaw-ridge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacksaw-ridge), [hell-or-high-water](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell-or-high-water), [hidden-figures](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-figures), [la-la-land](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-la-land), [lion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lion), [manchester-by-the-sea](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manchester-by-the-sea) and [moonlight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moonlight)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 5 and ~125 views) was asked by [*Chanandler Bong*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/19042), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Did John Glenn really ask for that?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68967/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What happened to Terrel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69104/49) (3 / ~40)
3. [Do Aliens intend to teach every human being the Universal language?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68940/49) (1 / ~113)

   [What was Ram planning to do with Saroo in Lion?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69251/49) (1 / ~11)
4. [Why was Dev Patel nominated for Supporting Actor rather than Best Actor?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69272/49) (-1 / ~6)

Comment: Thanks. I think it's only the second time I was taking part in WTC. I guess I should do it more often.