# Oscar 2018 Topic Challenge: The nominees for the Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Next Sunday sees the celebration of the [90th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90th_Academy_Awards). Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2651/49) this might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4159/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2018-02-26 00:00 UTC to 2018-03-04 23:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [call-me-by-your-name](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-me-by-your-name), [darkest-hour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darkest-hour), [dunkirk](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dunkirk), [get-out](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/get-out), [lady-bird](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lady-bird), [phantom-thread](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phantom-thread), [the-post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-post), [the-shape-of-water](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-shape-of-water) and [three-billboards-outside-ebbing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-billboards-outside-ebbing)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge. And you might also want to check out our [live chat event](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4171/49) during the actual ceremony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 24 and ~6,437 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Is Christopher Nolan's Dunkirk historically inaccurate in portraying absence of the Indian army?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/86030/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did Churchill really talk to people on the London Underground?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85996/49) (17 / ~5,053)
3. [Is Miguel adopted?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/86023/49) (3 / ~155)
4. [Why doesn't the deputy (played by Sam Rockwell) get arrested and charged after clearly assaulting the billboard manager?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/86167/49) (1 / ~13)