# Academy Awards Live Chat - 2016

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, chat

On February the 28th/29th (depending where you are) the [**88th Academy Awards (Oscar) ceremony**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/88th_Academy_Awards) will be held and broadcast live into the world. While not everyone might agree about their true artistic and critical significance, it isn't deniable that they're one of the biggest events in and about one of the biggest and most famous movie industries in the world. This might thus be a great chance for a **simultaneous live chat event during the ceremony**, which could help to make users aware of the chat, and maybe even a few SE users aware of our site.

So [like last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1614/49) we are holding a corresponding **[live chat event on 2016-02-29 1:00 - 6:00 UTC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=schedule)** for discussing anything Oscar, be it how <s>bad</s> good of a host Chris Rock is, how *The Room* could get nominated for best picture or why Leo had to eat a bison liver to finally get an Oscar...

Comment: Would he have been more likely or less like to win the Oscar if the bear story had turned out to be true?

Comment: @Richard Save that for the actual chat discussion.

Comment: Alas, I don't think I've seen any of the nominated films. Historically, I haven't found most of the Oscar picks especially interesting. I haven't looked at the nominations this year, but I'm guessing it'll be much the same.

Comment: @Richard Grrrrrr......  I will leave it to you to guess if I am impersonating the bear or if I am growling at you regarding your comment about the bear story.  Hehehe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oscars are over and so is the live chat event. Over the [course of the event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1888/2016/2/29) we had  different users chatting and I want to thank everyone for participating and hope you enjoyed it (along with the actual award show, of course).

In addition to that, *Catija* made a little survey for everyone to vote on their own favourites for various specific awards, the results of which [can be viewed here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1dpfn8f7vfDd5eLS2UmQIINYZ6CY1Y2TznBzQLsyVY3s/viewanalytics?usp=form_confirm).

I'm looking forward to next year's Academy Awards Chat.