# Academy Awards Live Chat - 2017

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, chat

On February the 26th/27th (depending where you are) the [**89th Academy Awards (Oscar) ceremony**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards) will be held and broadcast live into the world. While not everyone might agree about their true artistic and critical significance, it isn't deniable that they're one of the biggest events in and about one of the biggest and most famous movie industries in the world. This might thus be a great chance for a **simultaneous live chat event during the ceremony**, which could help to make users aware of the chat, and maybe even a few SE users aware of our site.

So [like last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2164/49) we are holding a corresponding [**live chat event on 2017-02-27 1:00 - 6:00 UTC**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=schedule) for discussing anything Oscar.

Comment: Do we want a poll?

Comment: Hmmm... That link doesn't seem to work any more. [Try this one](https://goo.gl/forms/YcFpxqdd6FaBUUCj2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oscars are over and so is the live chat event. Over [the course](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/conversation/academy-awards-live-chat-2017-part-1) of [the event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/conversation/academy-awards-live-chat-2017-part-2) we had a whole of 11 different users chatting and I want to thank everyone for participating and hope you enjoyed it (along with the actual award show, of course).

In addition to that, *Catija* made a little survey for everyone to vote on their own favourites for various specific awards, the results of which [can be viewed here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1SZjs5uZAx6Rktz-RfLkJiLJy5I2w-DXninXwJ8hxnt8/edit#responses).

I'm looking forward to next year's Academy Awards Chat.