# Academy Awards Live Chat - 2018

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, chat

On March the 4th/5th (depending where you are) the [**90th Academy Awards (Oscar) ceremony**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90th_Academy_Awards) will be held and broadcast live into the world. While not everyone might agree about their true artistic and critical significance, it isn't deniable that they're one of the biggest events in and about one of the biggest and most famous movie industries in the world. This might thus be a great chance for a **simultaneous live chat event during the ceremony**, which could help to make users aware of the chat, and maybe even a few SE users aware of our site.

So [like last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2652/49) we are holding a corresponding [**live chat event on 2018-03-05 1:00 - 6:00 UTC**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=schedule) for discussing anything Oscar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oscars are over and so is the live chat event. Over [the course of the event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/conversation/academy-awards-2018-live-chat) we had a whole of 10 different users chatting and I want to thank everyone for participating and hope you enjoyed it (along with the actual award show, of course).

I'm looking forward to next year's Academy Awards Chat.

Comment: yep, me too. ;-)