# Academy Awards Live Chat - 2019

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, chat

On February the 24th/25th (depending where you are) the [**91st Academy Awards (Oscar) ceremony**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/91st_Academy_Awards) will be held and broadcast live into the world. While not everyone might agree about their true artistic and critical significance, it isn't deniable that they're one of the biggest events in and about one of the biggest and most famous movie industries in the world. This might thus be a great chance for a **simultaneous live chat event during the ceremony**, which could help to make users aware of the chat, and maybe even a few SE users aware of our site.

So [like last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4171/49) we are holding a corresponding [**live chat event on 2019-02-25 1:00 - 6:00 UTC**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=schedule) for discussing anything Oscar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oscars are over and so is the live chat event. Over [the course of the event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/conversation/academy-awards-2019-live-chat) we had a whole of 9 different users chatting and I want to thank everyone for participating and hope you enjoyed it (along with the actual award show, of course).