# Oscar 2019 Topic Challenge: The nominees for the Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Next Sunday sees the celebration of the [91st Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/91st_Academy_Awards). Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4172/49) this might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4430/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2019-02-18 00:00 UTC to 2019-02-25 1:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [black-panther](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-panther), [blackkklansman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackkklansman), [bohemian-rhapsody](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bohemian-rhapsody), [the-favourite](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-favourite), [green-book](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-book), [roma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roma), [a-star-is-born](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-star-is-born) and [vice](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vice)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge. And you might also want to check out our [live chat event](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4443/49) during the actual ceremony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only and thus top-voted question (with a score of 14 and ~6,531 views) was asked by [*Michael Reid*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/70675), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why is it a problem for Freddie if the guys from Munich did what he wanted?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97209/49)