# Oscar 2020 Topic Challenge: The nominees for Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Next Sunday sees the celebration of the [92nd Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/92nd_Academy_Awards). Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4444/49) this might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2020-02-03 00:00 UTC to 2020-02-10 1:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [ford-v-ferrari](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ford-v-ferrari), [the-irishman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-irishman), [jojo-rabbit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojo-rabbit), [joker](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joker), [little-women](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-women), [marriage-story](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-story), [1917](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1917), [once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood), and [parasite](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parasite)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 5 and ~288 views) was asked by [*Mishra Shreyanshu*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/40409), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did Carroll Shelby toss a nut into the Ferrari pit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106566/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why does Schofield hear church bells when the church is on fire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106599/49) (3 / ~67)
3. [Why did Ken Miles say, "Head Gasket" in this scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106557/49) (-3 / ~123)