# Oscar 2021 Topic Challenge: The nominees for Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Yesterday saw the belated celebration of the [93rd Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/93rd_Academy_Awards). Like [last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4623/49) this might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year beforehand. So we're starting a new **biweekly topic challenge. From 2021-04-26 00:00 UTC to 2021-05-09 23:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [nomadland](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomadland), [the-father](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-father), [judas-and-the-black-messiah](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judas-and-the-black-messiah), [mank](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mank), [minari](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minari), [promising-young-woman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promising-young-woman), [sound-of-metal](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-of-metal), and [the-trial-of-the-chicago-seven](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-trial-of-the-chicago-seven)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/weekly-topic-challenge-ideas) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the challenge is over and, like the awards themselves, the results were rather...underwhelming. The only question (with a score of -2 and ~102 views) was asked by a now deleted user, which makes them the winner of this challenge:

### 1. [How did Orson Welles prepare final cut without any draft?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/113514/49)

At least it led to a good answer, though.