# Academy Awards Live Chat - 2020

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, chat

On February the 9th/10th (depending where you are) the [**92nd Academy Awards (Oscar) ceremony**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/92nd_Academy_Awards) will be held and broadcast live into the world. While not everyone might agree about their true artistic and critical significance, it isn't deniable that they're one of the biggest events in and about one of the biggest and most famous movie industries in the world. This might thus be a great chance for a **simultaneous live chat event during the ceremony**, which could help to make users aware of the chat, and maybe even a few SE users aware of our site.

So [like last year](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4443/49) we are holding a corresponding [**live chat event on 2020-02-10 0:00 - 5:00 UTC**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=schedule) for discussing anything Oscar.

Comment: This could benefit from being featured, in case it doesn't make it to Hot Meta Posts

Comment: @Jenayah It is, for more than a day already. ;-)

Comment: Eh, blame mobile web :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oscars are over and so is the live chat event. Over [the course of the event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/conversation/academy-awards-2020-live-chat) we had a whole of 5 different users chatting and I want to thank everyone for participating and hope you enjoyed it (along with the actual award show, of course).